# Remove all [tag:custom]-isation

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

There is no usage for the [custom](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom) tag, and it doesn't seem to add anything but noise.

Currently it is applied to 33 questions, a few recent ones, mostly quite old questions. All of them appear to have other useful tags and do not appear as if they would care having this tag removed.

Cleanup time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, this tag serves no purpose and should be cleaned up.

Comment: Cool. I've removed the first few. Will do some more tomorrow to avoid spamming the home page.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I've removed some over the past few days, too.

Comment: Ah, I thought there seemed fewer than I remembered!